# jQuery Selector Question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a quick question about jQuery selectors.

Is doing this:

```
$('.class_el_1, .class_el_2').hide();
```

The same as just looping through each element using jQuery's .each function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has the same *effect* of hiding them all, but it's not exactly the same internally, no.  [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) takes a callback in which `this` can be used to do specific things to *each* element, so it does a bit more work.  [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) in a chain just sets `display: none;` on the elements (storing their previous value).

[You can see how it works internally here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L61), for your call with no parameters:

```
for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
  var old = jQuery.data(this[i], "olddisplay");
  if ( !old && old !== "none" ) {
    jQuery.data( this[i], "olddisplay", jQuery.css( this[i], "display" ) );
  }
}

// Set the display of the elements in a second loop
// to avoid the constant reflow
for ( var j = 0, k = this.length; j < k; j++ ) {
  this[j].style.display = "none";
}
```

In the above `this` refers to the element set that `$('.class_el_1, .class_el_2')` matched, just using a `for` loop to literate over them.

Comment: ah gotcha... but using a comma delimited list just allows you to modify more than one element?

Comment: @dennismonsewicz - Yup, that's a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), even just `.class` can get many elements, the comma separation lets you combine multiple selectors, and `.hide()` (or whatever really) will act on *all* of the matches...think CSS, they work exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! This answered SO much!